# How to calculate approximately the connection speed of a website using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, connection, widget

How to calculate approximately the connection speed of a website using JavaScript?

I want to create a javascript widget like, which will calculate the speed opening the current opened page.

I am asking if this can be done using just javascript and what will be the idea.

**Update**

Note that the page size is always Unknown.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here](http://stimpy77.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!FE05918FD4D775C5!382.entry)'s an example using AJAX with .Net backend, though it could be anything.

[Here](http://www.phaster.com/golden_hill_free_web/ghfw_connection_speed.shtml)'s a simpler example using an image.

The key is to have a page/object of a known size and capture the start and end times as the browser retrieves it.  Then simply divide the size by some [unit of time] to get [size] per [unit of time].  Then use math to translate this into whatever you want.

Answer (score -2):

Sure.

```
<script>
    startTime = Date.now();
    window.onload = function(){
        endTime = Date.now();
        //Time in ms between opening page, and loading all the date
        alert(endTime - startTime)
    };
</script>
```

Now to approximate speed. Statically you know let's say page is 200kb.

```
var kbps = 200 / (endTime - startTime * 1000);
```

Comment: and what if i don't know whats the page size in kb, can i get using js as well?

Comment: Javascript has no way of checking file-sizes of pages unfortunately, so I would have to say no.

Comment: This will not get you the connection speed. That gives you the load time the page takes to render.

Comment: so how to get it? there is a smarter way?

Comment: The last line, calculates the average speed with which the page has loaded.