# How to measure data consumed on a site with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a library or native javascript way for calculating the amount of data that was send and received in bytes by visiting a site? e.g. How do I measure the size of a get request in bytes?

Comment: Please describe what you mean exactly by "amount of data". Also, please share the research you've done so far (and do it if you haven't).

Comment: I think this has been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890221/how-to-get-current-page-size-in-kb-using-just-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        var pageData= $('html').html().length;
    }
);
```

this will get you the data size in MB.

Comment: This seems to fail horribly on `<html><script>for(var i=0; i<10000; i++)document.write(i)</script></html>`

Comment: Something like this but this will only get me the size of the page that I've just visited not any requests... How do I get any requests or new data loaded?