# Page size in kb with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, size

Is there any way to read with javascript the total page size (with resources loaded) in kb of a html document?

Edit: Please read carefully. It's not a duplicate. I want to get the total loaded page size, including all resources, like css, images and scripts. Come on stack overflow ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current page size in KB using just javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890221/how-to-get-current-page-size-in-kb-using-just-javascript)

Comment: Nope it's not a duplicate. I want to count all the resources that a page loads including css, js and images. The TOTAL size of the page. The html size or performing an XMLHttpRequest don't solve my question.

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890221/how-to-get-current-page-size-in-kb-using-just-javascript

Answer (score -1):

You can use this website to get the information on all loaded items on the website page
http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know there are a lot of websites out there which do this kind of thing. But i was aiming in doing it from javascript...